# Why does MERCURIAL_REVISION return the value NULL when I try accessing it on Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, mercurial, jenkins-groovy, mercurial-hook

On Mercurial I've implemented a hook in my hgrc file that activates when some sort of change occurs in Jenkins(i.e tagging or committing). Here is my hook code:

`curl -X POST http://tokenusername:115d59a462df750d4f12347975b3d691cf@127.0.0.1:8080/job/pipelinejob/buildWithParameters/mercurial/notifyCommit?url=http://127.0.0.1:85/hg/experimentrepoistory?token=1247`

So there's no issue with my hook notifying Jenkins that a change has occurred and the pipeline executes but for some reason I am having trouble getting the commit id or any or the author name's who made the commit etc. I went to the script console in jenkins and wrote the following code in groovy to see if the changeset data from Mercurial transferred over to Jenkins. Also all the libraries are imported

```
def job = hudson.model.Hudson.instance.getItem("pipelinejob")
def builds = job.getBuilds()
def thisBuild = builds[0]
println('Lets test Mercurial fields ' + thisBuild.getEnvironment()['MERCURIAL_REVISION']) //Lets test Mercurial fields null
```

It makes me think that MERCURIAL_REVISION for some reason wasnt defined even though I provided a job that has the changeset info. I was reading this documentation https://javadoc.jenkins.io/plugin/mercurial/hudson/plugins/mercurial/MercurialChangeSet.html#MercurialChangeSet-- that lists a bunch of functions that have alot of functions like `getCommitId()` `getNode()` etc that gets the information that I need. Problem is I'm not entirely sure how to instantiate MercurialChangeSet with the jenkin jobs pipelinejob that in theory should have the Mercurial commitId information. Thats why I wanted to know if I perhaps missed something obvious regarding accessing MERCURIAL_REVISION

Answer (score 0):

So I found out that I need to enable the Pipeline script from SCM and that I need to put the Jenkinsfile with the pipeline code inside my workspace directory in order to get the changeset information. I am not entirely sure why this works since I would think the Jenkinsfile needs to be in the repo directory of the SCM